# Convergence of an aggregate remainder in a logarithmic expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, probability-theory, inequality, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

Let $(x_j)_j$ be an ergodic and stationary sequence of random variables such that $E[x_j]=0$ (for all $j$) and:

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n}f(x_j) \to E[f(x)] < \infty, \quad (n \to \infty)$$

for any function. We know that:

$$\log(1 + z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1} z^{k+1} =z + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} z^k,\quad z \in \mathbb C,  |z|< 1.$$

I know that for the real case, when $z$ is close to zero, I can assume $\log(1+z) \approx z$ and thus discard the remainder term (last term of the last equation above). Anyway, we have for $n$ large enough and for any $t \in \mathbb R$, fixed but arbitrary:

$$\log\left(1 + \frac{a}{n}[e^{itx_j} - 1] \right) = \frac{a}{n}[e^{itx_j} - 1] + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} \left( \frac{a}{n}[e^{itx_j} - 1] \right)^k.$$

For the complex case, I believe we can still assume the remainder is negligible.

But I'm not comfortable doing that when aggregating:

$$\sum_{j=0}^n\ln\left(1 + \frac{a}{n}[e^{itx_j} - 1] \right) = \frac{a}{n}\sum_{j=0}^n [e^{itx_j} - 1] + \underbrace{\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} \left( \frac{a}{n}[e^{itx_j} - 1] \right)^k}_{\hbox{aggregate remainder}}$$

Note that

$$\frac{a}{n}\sum_{j=0}^n[e^{itx_j} - 1] \longrightarrow aE[e^{itx} - 1], \quad (n \to \infty)$$

Therefore, I would like to show that the aggregate remainder can also be discarded (goes to zero as $n \to \infty$).

**My attempt:**

We know that
$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k} \left( \frac{a}{n}[e^{itx_j} - 1] \right)^k \longrightarrow 0, \quad (n \to \infty)$$

When we add from $j=0$ to $n$ these elements, the aggregate up to $n$ will not necessarily tend to $0$, as infinite sums of negligible elements are not necessarily negligible. Thus, I would like to robustly prove that the aggregate indeed goes to zero when $n$ goes to infinity.
Can you help?